# Is there a way to request a .mov file by curl without setting a mimetype manually?

Tags: http, curl, request, mime-types

I'm trying to send a .mov file to my server with curl. like this.

```
curl -X POST -F "file1=@thumbnail.jpg" -F "file2=@data.mov" http://123.456.789/api/item
```

Then, Server can get a correct mimetype of .jpg(`image/jpeg`) but the mimetype of .mov was `application/octet-stream`

i want to send a .mov file with mimetype `video/quicktime` without setting content-type manually.

Is that possible?